# Cannot mount GPT Windows partition

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, 14.10, gpt

I had a Windows 7 machine with 167GB. I wanted to install Ubuntu on it, so I shrank the partition into 111GB and 56GB. Afterwards I installed Ubuntu 14.10 32-bit in the newly created 56GB partition.

Now Ubuntu boots very well, but I cannot boot into Windows 7 nor can I mount the Windows 7 partition in Ubuntu. Can anyone please help?

Here is the fdisk output:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 167,7 GiB, 180045766656 bytes, 351651888 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x528025a8

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 234141695 234139648 111,7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       234141696 351649791 117508096    56G 83 Linux
```

Here is the gdisk output:

```
$ sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.8

Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present

***************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format
in memory. 
***************************************************************

Disk /dev/sda: 351651888 sectors, 167.7 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 9E061B7E-6EF6-4F8E-BBEC-4FA6BF459929
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 351651854
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 4077 sectors (2.0 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048       234141695   111.6 GiB   0700  Microsoft basic data
   2       234141696       351649791   56.0 GiB    8300  Linux filesystem
```

Here is the blkid output on the windows partition:

```
$ sudo blkid /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1: PTTYPE="PMBR" PARTUUID="528025a8-01"
```

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: What errors do you get when you try to mount the partition. How do you mount it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you convert your disk to MBR style before installing Ubuntu?  Did you need to change any BIOS setting to install Ubuntu?  If yes, then you may need to restore that setting to be able to boot into Windows.

I had a GPT drive and I had to clean it (erase everything) and then convert it to MBR style, then repartition it for Windows and Linux separately and then re-installed Windows and Linux.  I used Fedora then.

Comment: Hi, I did not change any BIOS settings. When I was installing Ubuntu, it weirdly did not detect Windows. I did not particularly change from GPT to MBR. 

This is what I did,
1) Shrank the Windows partition using Windows Disk management
2) Selected, "Something else" and installed Ubuntu on the newly created partition obtained by shrinking

I have a doubt, does Ubuntu's installer automatically erase GPT and install MBR?

Comment: Found on internet that, Windows uses Hybrid MBR. Maybe Ubuntu's installer fell for the fake MBR and added a partition to it. I would like to know, if the /dev/sda1 is still instact and the data can be recovered. And if there is a possibility to mount it.

Comment: I think your data can still be recovered from the Windows partition provided you are able to boot into it since that's the only non-linux partition you have left.  Have you tried the Windows recovery disk yet?